# Flatten JSON with columns having values as a list in dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have the following data frame:

```
| Category | idlist                                                           |
| -------- | -----------------------------------------------------------------|
| new      | {100: ['1A', '2B'], 200: ['2A', '3B'], 300: ['3A', '3B', '4B']}  |
| old      |  ['99A', '99B']                                                  |
```

I want it to be converted into this:

```
| Category | id  | list                 |
| -------- | --- | -------------------- |
| new      | 100 | ['1A', '2B']         |     
| new      | 200 | ['2A', '3B']         |
| new      | 300 | ['3A', '3B', '4B']   |
| old      | -1  | ['99A', '99B']       |
```

The column 'idlist' is a json for category new with id as key and value a list of items. Then there is category that is old and it just has a list of items and since it doesn't have any id we can default it to -1 or 0.

I was trying some examples on internet but I was not able to flatten the json for category new because the key is a number. Can this be achieved? I can handle the old separately as a subset by putting id as '-1' because I really don't need to flatten the cell corresponding to old. But is there a way to handle all this together?

As requested, I am sharing the original JSON format before I converted it into a df:

```
{'new' : {100: ['1-A', '2-B'], 200: ['2-A', '3-B'], 300: ['3-A', '3-B', '4-B']}, 'old' :  ['99-A', '99-B']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original JSON of this:

```py
jj = '''
{
 "new": {"100": ["1A", "2B"], "200": ["2A", "3B"], "300": ["3A", "3B", "4B"]},
 "old": ["99A", "99B"]
}
'''
```

I think it's easier to pre-process the JSON rather than post-process the dataframe:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

dd = json.loads(jj)
ml = []
for k, v in dd.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        ml += [{ 'Category' : k, 'id' : k2, 'list' : v2 } for k2, v2 in v.items()]
    else:
        ml += [{ 'Category' : k, 'id' : -1, 'list' : v }]

df = pd.DataFrame(ml)
```

Output:

```
  Category   id          list
0      new  100      [1A, 2B]
1      new  200      [2A, 3B]
2      new  300  [3A, 3B, 4B]
3      old   -1    [99A, 99B]
```

Comment: @trojanhorse if this isn't the correct starting point, please do edit your question with the actual JSON and I'll happily edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help. However, the json doesnt have the column name. It is more like - {'new': {100:.....},'old': [''99A'...]}. I am breaking it at the source of creation and using it to combine

Comment: I am putting the JSON in the question. Give me 2 mins. Edit: Added the json

Comment: @trojanhorse I've updated the answer to suit your actual JSON

Comment: hey, but the ids are not in quotes. It is 100 and not "100". I tried changing the json into string but it gives me JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Comment: @trojanhorse so is that a string or an actual dict? what does `type(yourvar)` give?

Comment: It is a dict for sure, Nick. When I try your code it gives the error - TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict. I wrapped the dict in str() method and then the above error. I guess it is with the id, no? They are not in inverted commas as supposed to be ideally.

Comment: @trojanhorse Sorry, my bad, I had assumed from the title that you started with a JSON. If your value is already a dict, no need to go through the `json.loads` at all. Just substitute your variable name for `dd` in the `for` loop and it should work.

Comment: yeah, that does the trick and is pretty fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ebis.png)

```
   def function1(s:pd.Series):
    global df2
    list1 = []
    var1=eval(s.idlist)
    if isinstance(var1,dict):
        for i in var1:
            list1.append({'Category':s.Category,'id':i,'list':var1[i]})
    else:
        list1.append({'Category':s.Category,'id':-1,'list':var1})
    df2=pd.concat([df2,pd.DataFrame(list1)])

df2=pd.DataFrame()
df1.apply(function1,axis=1)
df2.set_index('Category')
```

Comment: this was amazing. I learnt something new with the eval. I got a type error with the eval but I was able to resolve it after converting the argument to string

Comment: @trojanhorse If you have to solve your problem with `eval`, you have two problems. Google "eval is evil" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks for the heads up. Let me read it up. Thanks for your solution too :)

Comment: Note that changing to `ast.literal_eval` will make it safe

Answer (score 1):

1. First isolate new and old in separate dataframes.
2. Create new columns corresponding to each key in the idlist dictionary for df_new.
3. Use pd.melt to "unpivot" df_new
4. Modify df_old to match column for column with df_new,
5. Use pd.concat to rejoin the two dataframes on axis 0 (rows).

See below:

```
# Recreated before you json file was attached    
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['new', 'old'], 
               'idlist': [{100: ['1A', '2B'], 200: ['2A', '3B'], 300: ['3A', '3B', '4B']}, ['99A', '99B']]})

# isolate new and old in separate dataframes
df_new = df[df['Category'] == "new"]
df_old = df[df['Category'] == "old"]

# Create new columns corresponding to each key in the idlist dictionary for df_new
my_dict = df_new['idlist'][0]
keys = list(my_dict.keys())
values = list(my_dict.values())

for k,v in zip(keys, values):
    df_new[k] = f"{v}" # F-string to format the values in output as "string lists"

# Drop idlist because you don't need it anymore
df_new = df_new.drop('idlist', 1)


# Use pd.melt to "unpivot" df_new
df_new = pd.melt(df_new, 
        id_vars='Category', 
        value_vars=list(df_new.columns[1:]),
        var_name='id', 
        value_name='list')

# Modify df_old to match column for column with df_new
df_old['list'] = df_old['idlist']
df_old = df_old.drop('idlist', axis = 1)
df_old['id'] = -1

# Use pd.concat to rejoin the two dataframes on axis 0 (rows)
clean_df = pd.concat([df_new, df_old], axis = 0).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Modified to include step of dropping "idlist" column because you don't need it anymore

Comment: Awesome, glad you found it helpful. Let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), this can be accomplished without using loops.
- The data in the OP is a `dict`, not a JSON string.

  - A `dict` or `JSON` from an API, that isn't a `str`, can be loaded directly into pandas.

    - `data = {"new": {"100": ["1-A", "2-B"], "200": ["2-A", "3-B"], "300": ["3-A", "3-B", "4-B"]}, "old": ["99-A", "99-B"]}` - This is a `dict`
  - If the data is a `str`, then use `data = json.loads(json_str)`, where `json_str` is your data.

    - `json_str = '{"new": {"100": ["1-A", "2-B"], "200": ["2-A", "3-B"], "300": ["3-A", "3-B", "4-B"]}, "old": ["99-A", "99-B"]}'` - This is a JSON string because it's surrounded by quotes.

```py
import json
import pandas

# 1. load data into pandas
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# 2. melt the dataframe from wide to lone form
df = df.melt(var_name='Category', value_name='list')

# 3. split the numbers from the Category column and add -1
df[['Category', 'id']] = df.Category.str.split('.', expand=True).fillna(-1)
```

### `df` views:

#### `1.`

```
            old     new.100     new.200          new.300
0  [99-A, 99-B]  [1-A, 2-B]  [2-A, 3-B]  [3-A, 3-B, 4-B]
```

#### `2.`

```
  Category             list
0      old     [99-A, 99-B]
1  new.100       [1-A, 2-B]
2  new.200       [2-A, 3-B]
3  new.300  [3-A, 3-B, 4-B]
```

#### `3.`

```
  Category             list   id
0      old     [99-A, 99-B]   -1
1      new       [1-A, 2-B]  100
2      new       [2-A, 3-B]  200
3      new  [3-A, 3-B, 4-B]  300
```